# Can not move fragment when click navigation view

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

When i click item in navigation but not move new frament
I think i wrong in function replace fragment 
**fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.ad_linear, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);**

Anyone help me fix issue
Thanks

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements MaterialTabListener {
    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    MaterialTabHost tabHost;
    ViewPager pager;

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private String[] tabs =  {"Home","Category","Favourite"};
    Toolbar toolbar;
    String strMessage;
    private AdView mAdView;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitial;
    private String name, link;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private View navHeader;
    private ImageView imgNavHeaderBg, imgProfile;
    private TextView txtName, txtWebsite;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;



    // index to identify current nav menu item
    public static int navItemIndex = 0;

    // tags used to attach the fragments
    private static final String TAG_HOME = "home";
    public static String CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;

    // toolbar titles respected to selected nav menu item
    private String[] activityTitles;

    // flag to load home fragment when user presses back key
    private boolean shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress = true;
    private Handler mHandler;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            toolbar = (Toolbar) this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            tabHost = (MaterialTabHost) this.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
            pager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.pager );
            adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            pager.setAdapter(adapter);

            pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // when user do a swipe the selected tab change
                    tabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

                }
            });

            for(String tab_name:tabs)
            {
                tabHost.addTab(
                        tabHost.newTab()
                                .setText(tab_name)
                                .setTabListener(MainActivity.this)
                );
            }
            //navigation

        mHandler = new Handler();

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);


        // Navigation view header
        navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        txtName = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtWebsite = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.website);
        imgNavHeaderBg = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_header_bg);
        imgProfile = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_profile);

        // load toolbar titles from string resources
        activityTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);



        // load nav menu header data
        loadNavHeader();

        // initializing navigation menu
        setUpNavigationView();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            navItemIndex = 0;
            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
            loadHomeFragment();
        }

            //end navigation



    }

//navigation

    private void loadNavHeader() {
        // name, website
        txtName.setText("Ravi Tamada");
        txtWebsite.setText("www.androidhive.info");

        // loading header background image
        Glide.with(this).load(urlNavHeaderBg)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imgNavHeaderBg);

        // Loading profile image
        Glide.with(this).load(urlProfileImg)
                .crossFade()
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imgProfile);

        // showing dot next to notifications label
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setActionView(R.layout.menu_dot);
    }


    private void setUpNavigationView() {
        //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                    case R.id.home:
                        navItemIndex = 0;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_photos:
                        navItemIndex = 1;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_PHOTOS;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_movies:
                        navItemIndex = 2;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_MOVIES;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_notifications:
                        navItemIndex = 3;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_NOTIFICATIONS;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_settings:
                        navItemIndex = 4;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SETTINGS;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_about_us:
                        // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeFragment.class));
                        drawer.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_privacy_policy:
                        // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeFragment.class));
                        drawer.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        navItemIndex = 0;
                }

                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                }
                menuItem.setChecked(true);

                loadHomeFragment();

                return true;
            }
        });


        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //calling sync state is necessary or else your hamburger icon wont show up
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    private void selectNavMenu() {
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
    }
    private void loadHomeFragment() {
        // selecting appropriate nav menu item
        selectNavMenu();

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
            drawer.closeDrawers();

            // show or hide the fab button

            return;
        }

        // Sometimes, when fragment has huge data, screen seems hanging
        // when switching between navigation menus
        // So using runnable, the fragment is loaded with cross fade effect
        // This effect can be seen in GMail app
        Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // update the main content by replacing fragments
                Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                        android.R.anim.fade_out);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.ad_linear, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
                fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
        };

        // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
        if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
            mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
        }

        // show or hide the fab button


        //Closing drawer on item click
        drawer.closeDrawers();

        // refresh toolbar menu
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
        switch (navItemIndex) {
            case 0:
                // home
                HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                return homeFragment;
            case 1:
                // photos
                PhotosFragment photosFragment = new PhotosFragment();
                return photosFragment;
            case 2:
                // movies fragment
                CategoryFragment moviesFragment = new CategoryFragment();
                return moviesFragment;
            case 3:
                // notifications fragment
                CategoryFragment notificationsFragment = new CategoryFragment();
                return notificationsFragment;

            case 4:
                // settings fragment
                CategoryFragment settingsFragment = new CategoryFragment();
                return settingsFragment;
            default:
                return new HomeFragment();
        }
    }
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        return;
    }

    // This code loads home fragment when back key is pressed
    // when user is in other fragment than home
    if (shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress) {
        // checking if user is on other navigation menu
        // rather than home
        if (navItemIndex != 0) {
            navItemIndex = 0;
            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
            loadHomeFragment();
            return;
        }
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}



    //end navigation
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(MaterialTab tab) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(MaterialTab tab) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(MaterialTab tab) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

        }

        public Fragment getItem(int num) {

            switch (num) {
                case 0:
                    return new HomeFragmentCheck();
                case 1:
                    return new CategoryFragmentCheck();
                case 2:
                    return new FavouriteFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.home, menu);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
    {       
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) 
        {
        case R.id.about: 
            Intent intab=new Intent(MainActivity.this,AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intab);
            break;

            case R.id.update:

                showPU();

                break;


        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
        }
        return true;



    }


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">





    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/m_tab_clr"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

        <it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
            android:id="@+id/tabHost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            app:accentColor="@color/m_tab_select_accent_clr"
            app:primaryColor="@color/m_tab_clr" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/ad_linear"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tabHost" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ad_linear"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >


        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:context="com.app.apk.MainActivity">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></FrameLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();                        
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                                android.R.anim.fade_out);
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Not woking i think i wrong in R.id.ad_linear but i dont know fix

Comment: anyone help me fix